# Como faço para fazer um recyclerview meu aparecer numa tab em vez de fixo na main?

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

Criei um recyclerview na main que está ok, tbm criei 2 tabs que estão ok. Mas quando troco entre as tabs o recycler view fica fixo na tela em vez de aparecer apenas na tab1. Um amigo me falou que eu precisava usar context mas nem entendi o que é isso, e então alguém tem uma sugestão?

```
 //RecyclerView

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
String[] materias = {"Português", "Matemática", "Inglês"};
Double[] notas = {7.5, 10.0, 2.7};
Integer[] faltas = {5, 6, 3};

//Fim do RecyclerView
```

**Agora dentro do OnCreate**

```
 recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
 recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(materias, notas, faltas);
 layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
 recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
 recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
```

**Tabs**

```
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs);


    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);


    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); 


    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorPrimary);

            }
        });

    // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);


}
```

Comment: Posta o código que vc está usando, é melhor pra te ajudar

Comment: pronto, coloquei o que era relevante.

Comment: Acredito que você precisa chamar os recyclerView dentro da Adapter do Viewpager

Answer (score 0):

A activity conterá um fragment para cada tab. Cada fragment conterá um recyclerview.

Estrutura:

```
-activity1|-tab1-fragment1-recyclerview1
          |-tab2-fragment2-recyclerview2
```

Em questão de fluxo de execução: o activity_main.xml contém um widget chamado viewpager. 
Na MainActivity.class, você chama o Viewpager e seta nele um adapter. O Adapter é uma classe especial que dentro dela conterá tantos fragmentos. Cada fragmento é um xml e uma classe, também. Cada fragmento representa o conteúdo de uma tab.
Dentro de cada xml dos fragments, você cria um (widget)recyclerview. Dentro de cada classe de cada fragmento, você programa a execução do recyclerview.